# Event delegation problem on a drag and resize rectangles on an image with React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I cannot find a way to detect a click on the resize corner of a div with React.

I'm working on a component that's displaying rectangles, and I want to allow the user to drag them around, and resize each rectangle.

The problem is the div that's containing the resize-corner is not receiving the onMouseDown event, only its parent. This is a problem because on a click on the resize corner, I want to disable the drag feature.

Here's my code, let me know what you guys think about that.

```
   const handleMouseDownDragging = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log('Is resizing: ', isResizing);
      if (isResizing) {
         setIsResizing(true);
         return;
      }

      event.preventDefault();
      setIsDragging(true);
      setOffset({
         x: event.clientX - position.x,
         y: event.clientY - position.y
      });
   };

   const handleMouseMoveDragging = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (isResizing) {
         return;
      }

      event.preventDefault();
      if (isDragging) {
         setPosition({
            x: event.clientX - offset.x,
            y: event.clientY - offset.y
         });
      }
   };

   const handleMouseUpDragging = () => {
      console.log('Mouse up triggered');
      setIsDragging(false);
      setIsResizing(false);
   };


   const handleMouseDownResize = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log('****Resize triggered');
      setIsResizing(true);
      // setOffset({
      //    x: event.clientX - position.x,
      //    y: event.clientY - position.y
      // });
   };

   return (
      <>


         <div
            ref={ref}
            className={'hotspot'}
            style={{
               left: position.x,
               top: position.y,
               width: `${(width * 100) / imageWidth}%`,
               height: `${(height * 100) / imageHeight}%`,
               position: 'absolute',
               cursor: 'move',
               resize: 'both',
               overflow: 'auto'
            }}
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDownDragging}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMoveDragging}
            onMouseUp={handleMouseUpDragging}
         >
            <div
               style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  width: '10px',
                  height: '10px',
                  cursor: 'se-resize'
               }}
               onMouseDown={handleMouseDownResize}
            />
         </div>
      </>
   );
```